# How to find different items between mulitiple lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

I am trying to figure out how to compare `n` lists to find the different items.

For example, consider the list:

```
list_l = [[1,2,3,4,5,100], 
          [1,2,31,41,51], 
          [10,2,3,45,25],  
          [4,20,3,4,12,51,200]
         ]
```

Each item is unique for each list in `list_l`. e.g. the list `[1,2,3,4,5,100]` has no duplicate elements. The same goes for the list `[1,2,31,41,51]`, etc...

```
find_differences(list_l)
```

Expected outputs

```
res = [[5, 100], [31, 41], [10, 45, 25], [20, 12, 200]]
[5, 100] # elements of this list appears only in list [1,2,3,4,5,100]
[31, 41] # elements of this list appears only in list [1,2,31,41,51]
[10, 45, 25] # same here
[20, 12, 200] # same here
```

This example only has 4 lists and few items. However, my use case has many more lists and each list contains hundreds of items.

Using the `set` function gives a `list` of differences between the input lists. The resulting list, however, does not make it possible to distinguish which item originally belongs to which list.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to my problem.

```
results = []
for init_list in list_l:
    temp = []
    for e in init_list:
        unique_item = True
        for each_list in list_l:
            # Check if e is not unique, and if init_list and each_list are not the same list    
            if e in each_list and init_list != each_list:
                unique_item = False
                break
                
        # concatenate all unique items of a list
        if unique_item:
            temp.append(e)

    results.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has sets which have an intersection and a difference property.

```
s1 = set([1,2,3,4,5,100])
s2 = set([1,2,31,41,51])
s1.difference(s2)
```

Using this you can do what you're attempting!

I am a little worried this is a homework problem, so I don't think it makes sense to fully elaborate here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question a set-theoretical approach is used. Final sublists not ordered since not specified.

```
list_l = # from above

n = set(range(len(list_l)))
list_new = []
for i in range(len(list_l)):
    unique_entries = set(list_l[i]).difference(sum(map(list_l.__getitem__, n.difference({i})), []))
    list_new.append(list(unique_entries))

print(list_new)
```